# Getting started running Saxon

Tags: xslt, command, line, saxon

The user documentation for my .net installation of Saxon says, after installation.

You can now run one of the sample stylesheets or queries that comes with the saxon-resources download. Assuming you installed into c:\saxon, make this your current directory, and type:
for XSLT (all on one line): 
bin\Transform -t -s:samples\data\books.xml 
     -xsl:samples\styles\books.xsl -o:c:\temp.html

The above command line does not execute. "
bin is not recognized as the name of  cmdlet, function, scriptfile or operable program

I correctly positioned myself in the installation directory. Help?

Comment: So which version of Saxon .NET have you installed on which OS, which command line shell do you use? The error message sounds as if you use a Powershell window, have you tried `.\bin\Transform -t -s:samples\data\books.xml -xsl:samples\styles\books.xsl -o:c:\temp.html` instead respectively whatever the shell suggests you when you type e.g `bi` and use auto-completion?

Comment: Hi, I have not been able to reproduce this error. I tried it on Windows 10: cmd and powershell. It works fine. Please can you give some more details of your environment.

Comment: I got it working. I think there is a tutorial with incorrect information for the net installation, but I can't find the place I was reading in the doc for this application that mis-informed me. For now, my needs are met.  Sorry for the bother.